# Google Maps timeline feature not working - says "Can't connect to Maps, try again"

Tags: google-maps, google-location-history

When I was trying to connect my past timeline events, I encountered an awkward situation.

It says "Can't connect to Maps, try again".

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error? Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: You can always re-install the application, would also help if you posted the logs so we can see what's causing the issue.

Comment: I tried to re-install the app. I've been thinking, Google may restricted this feature on Google Map for some countries. I don't know why but I really want to use it.

Comment: Same here. Would there be a list of countries where this features is not available ?

Comment: So far it seems that China mainland and South Korea is banned from this feature...

Comment: Changing time zone seems to help as per https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/y0dw2ymwW4E and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/aYQiMojpctw

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it gets disconnected internally.
So the app is non-functional.

You can always uninstall then reinstall the app.
That will reconnect it internally.

---

I see chatter in the comments about locations and time zones but that is not in the question, so my answer stands as written.

Comment: Reinstalling is not solving the issue.